# Thread silently crashes and disappears

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi

I have a thread that executes a polling operation once in 100 ms.
After some time the thread disappears for apparently no reason while the application keeps going.

Thread is not blocked, because if I print all the thread present in the application, the polling thread is not there.

The code is the following:

```
def run(self):
    logger.info('PollThread thread started...')

    last_poll_time = curr_ms() / 1000
    while not self._stop_event.isSet():
        logger.debug('will do stuff')

        # doing stuff

        logger.debug('done!')

        # sleep until next polling cycle
        curr_time = curr_ms() / 1000
        logger.debug('thread present 1')
        time_from_last_poll = curr_time - last_poll_time

        if IO_POLLING_PERIOD > time_from_last_poll:
            sleep_period = IO_POLLING_PERIOD - time_from_last_poll
            if sleep_period > IO_POLLING_PERIOD:
                sleep_period = IO_POLLING_PERIOD
                logger.debug('thread present 2')

            logger.debug('thread present 2')
            time.sleep(sleep_period)
            logger.debug('thread present 3')

        logger.debug('thread present 4')
        last_poll_time = curr_ms() / 1000
        logger.debug('thread present 5')

    logger.info('terminated....')
```

`curr_ms()` is defined in this way:

```
def curr_ms():
    return int(round(time.time() * 1000))
```

`IO_POLLING_PERIOD` is:

```
IO_POLLING_PERIOD = 0.1
```

Thread disappears after printing "thread present 1".
No messages are printed after that.

The debugging is particularly hard because the issue may happen once in a couple of days of running.
The code in running on a Raspberry Pi 1.

---

**Solved**: the thread was crashing because of an error in log string formatting. In the code I've presented above I've removed that line to clarify code structure. After adding a try/catch I was able to find the problem. Thread crash didn't cause application to exit.

Comment: Are you sure IO_POLLING_PERIOD is defined? What if you try to print it at that "thread present 1" line?

Comment: In any case, you could try to wrap the whole thing in a `try` block and use the `except` to log the error that occurs (since there is certainly an error occurring).

Comment: @xzoert, IO_POLLING_PERIOD is defined, otherwise the whole thing would not work. Thanks for the idea about `try`/`catch`, will try ;)